# Woocommerce variations not filtering out invalid combinations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

After updating Woocommerce to 2.6.12 my variable products are acting up on the frontend. For example I have a variable product with attributes for size and color. Not all colors are available in every size. Before the update Woocommerce would use AJAX to filter out incompatible choices in the next dropdown to prevent selecting products that don't exist. Now it shows all options whether they result in a valid product or not. Selecting an invalid product results in an alert box popping up stating:

> Sorry, no products matching your selection. Please choose a different
>   combination.

How can I make Woocommerce filter out the invalid attribute selections again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the fix looking through Woocommerce's github repo closed issues. [This user](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12843) had the same issue. The fix can be found [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12817#issuecomment-272908267). I downloaded the fix contained in the zip file and used it to replace the files found in `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/`. After refreshing the page the invalid choices get filtered out and everything works as normal again.

Answer (score 8):

This probably is due to the woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold.   If your product contains more variations than the threshold specifies, woocommerce will wait until all variation options have been selected by the user before determining if the selected combination of options is valid(in stock, exists, etc).

Just set the threshold to a higher value. If your product has 30 possible combinations(whether they actually exist or not) set the threshold to something higher than 30, like 1111 for example.

You can use the snippet below in your functions.php file.

```
/* Increase Woocommerce Variation Threshold */
function wc_ajax_variation_threshold_modify( $threshold, $product ){
  $threshold = '1111';
  return  $threshold;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'wc_ajax_variation_threshold_modify', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: How much can the threshold be incresed until it start impacting performance?

Comment: ado387 as far as performance impact, I think that all depends on your specific server as well as the specific site.  I would imagine this would vary greatly based on where/who you are hosted, database size, processing power etc.  It would probably be a good idea to stress test this if you think it might cause issues to your site.